# Returning value threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

Can any one please tell how to return placeholder value in my CODE 1 similar to that of CODE 2.
I need to return my (oBJ + MTL) loaded model name so that i can reference it to my other performing functions.

```
 **CODE 1:**


        function makePlatform() {
          var placeholder = new THREE.Object3D();

          var onProgress = function(xhr) {
            if (xhr.lengthComputable) {
              var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
              console.log(Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded');
            }
          };
          var onError = function(xhr) {};
          THREE.Loader.Handlers.add(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());
          var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
          mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('myhouse/');
          mtlLoader.setPath('myhouse/');
          mtlLoader.load('villa.mtl', function(materials) {
            materials.preload();
            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath('myhouse/');
            objLoader.load('villa.obj', function(object) {
              object.position.y = -5.0;
              object.scale.x = object.scale.y = object.scale.z = 0.05
              object.castShadow = true;
              object.receiveShadow = true;
              object.traverse(function(node) {
                if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                  node.castShadow = true;
                  node.receiveShadow = true;
                }
              });
              scene.add(object);
              object.name = "base" //unsuccessful reference
              placeholder.add(object); //unsuccessful reference

            }, onProgress, onError);
          });
          return placeholder; // nothing returned
        }



    referred CODE 2 :

        function makePlatform(jsonUrl, textureUrl, textureQuality) {
          var placeholder = new THREE.Object3D();
          var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(textureUrl);
          texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
          texture.anisotropy = textureQuality;
          var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
          loader.load(jsonUrl, function(geometry) {
            geometry.computeFaceNormals();
            var platform = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
              map: texture
            }));
            platform.name = "platform";
            placeholder.add(platform);
          });
          return placeholder;
        }
```

Please let me know where i'm going wrong in referencing my code 1.

I used this fps example for reference
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_fps.html

Comment: Do you mean it's returning nothing at all or it's returning an empty Object3D?

Comment: im not getting any error as such for that, but i believe its not returning anything. ( i feel my referencing is wrong )

Comment: It could be that `placeholder.add(object)` doesn't run until after the placeholder's been returned.

Comment: i need a reference like in the code 2, since my material loading is taken care of OBJ + MTL loader, is there any other way i can reference the loaded object.name just like platform.name in code 2 ?